# UIProgressView disappears after focus UISearchBar

Tags: ios, autolayout, uisearchbar, nslayoutconstraint, uiprogressview

I have a custom UINavigationController which has an UIProgressView inside.
All works fine except, UISearchBar in child ViewController.
As soon UISearchBar is active, the UIProgressView moves up.
If I cancel UISearchBar input, the UIProgressView disappears completely.

That must be a problem with my autolayout code:

> progress = [[UIProgressView alloc] init]; 
>   [[self view] addSubview:progress];
>
> UIView *navBar = [self navigationBar]; [[self view]
>   addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
>   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[navBar]-[progress(2@20)]"
>                                                                       options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
>                                                                       metrics:nil
>                                                                         views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(progress, navBar)]];
>
> [[self view] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
>   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[progress]|"
>                                                                       options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
>                                                                       metrics:nil
>                                                                         views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(progress)]];

How can I fix this?

[Issue video](https://vimeo.com/91304503)

[Complete NavigationController code](https://gist.github.com/TUNER88/10021402)

[image: Issue screenshots]

Comment: It seems like you haven't set the constraints to your view correctly, to check this.. try switching off AutoLayout feature and run the code..

Comment: @Harsh 'Use Auto Layout' toggle does not change anything